# Oracle Function that return table of number problems and performance

Tags: oracle, performance

I have (sometimes) a memory block in my oracle database that turn crasy... a lot of session sundenless block each other and the probleme is in a function that return a table of number and is use in another procedure.

Edit : Sessions is 'blocked' with **Read By Other Session Wait Event**

First, my table of number :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE liste_lots as TABLE OF number(10)
```

and in large the function who populate the table :

```
   function get_ot_idem_cursor( .. ) return liste_lots is
   res_type liste_lots;
   p_restriction_level number;

   cursor  curs_lvl_1 is select [...] ;                              
   row_lvl_1 curs_lvl_1%rowtype;         

   cursor curs_lvl_0 is  select [...] ;                         
   row_lvl_0 curs_lvl_0%rowtype;                                        

begin

    res_type := liste_lots();

     p_restriction_level := get_edi_line_restriction(p_edi_line);

     if p_restriction_level = 1 then

         open curs_lvl_1;
         loop
         fetch curs_lvl_1 into row_lvl_1;

         exit when curs_lvl_1%notfound;

             begin           

                  res_type.extend;
                  res_type(res_type.last) := row_lvl_1.lot_id;

             exception

             when others then 

                dbms_output.put_line('problème get_ot_idem_cursor ');
                dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);

                close curs_lvl_1;  

             end;

         end loop; 

         close curs_lvl_1;      


      else

         open curs_lvl_0;
         loop
         fetch curs_lvl_0 into row_lvl_0;

         exit when curs_lvl_0%notfound;

             begin           

                  res_type.extend;
                  res_type(res_type.last) := row_lvl_0.lot_id;

             exception

             when others then 

                dbms_output.put_line('problème get_ot_idem_cursor ');
                dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);

                close curs_lvl_0;

             end;

         end loop;          

         close curs_lvl_0;  

      end if;

      return res_type;   

       exception
       when others then
       if curs_lvl_0%isopen then
          close curs_lvl_0;
       end if;
        if curs_lvl_1%isopen then
          close curs_lvl_1;
       end if;

end;
```

and is used on another part like that :

```
liste_ots := get_ot_idem_cursor(v_lot, v_sr_ligne_lot.id );

         select min(l.lot_id) into result
        from lot l
       where l.des_tiers_id = p_pf_tiers_id
         and l.lot_nature = 'POS'
         and l.exp_tiers_id = v_sr_ligne_lot.ramasse_tiers_id                    
         and ot_id in ((select * from TABLE(liste_ots)))
         and l.lot_datheurcharg > sysdate - 3;
```

When the db become crasy (session block, very slow) this is the part of the code who is pointed :

```
select * from TABLE(liste_ots)
```

the problem is not all the time, then if you have any idea or advise...

thanks in advance (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Not directly related to your question: why don't you use the `FOR r IN cursor LOOP` construct instead of `OPEN / LOOP / FETCH / INTO / EXIT WHEN`? Is so much more elegant and shorter and you can get rid of all the cleanup code.

Comment: @Codo yes, you have completly right, this is just old code.. i 100% agree with you :)  add to the massive list of todos ^^

Comment: The code you show only reads data. Readers cannot block in Oracle. Can you check (e.g. with SQL Developer's lock reports) if you really have locks (and what kind of locks)? If it isn't locks, it might just be an expensive query, either a large table or a table with lots of uncommitted data. Can you check if one of the query appears in the list of expensive queries (e.g. SQL Developer's Top Query reports). Is it a system with lots of disks and caches, or just a small server with a single disk?

Comment: @Codo when i've got the problem, sessions 'blocked' are on 'read by other session' wait event. so, it's not a 'block' but a very lot and long wait event. so, why ? Readers cannot block but i have this crasy 'read by other session' :/ i don't know if it's my code generate this 'problem'. The server is a big server with lot of disk (ssd and hdd) connected with fiber switch. Drive by esx.

Comment: The *Read by Other Session* wait state is the same as the regular *Buffer Busy Wait* state except that at least one sessions has requested the same data slightly earlier. Overall, it's just a slow query. Can you investigate the queries? Are they expensive? Is the session waiting for table data or for UNDO log data?

Comment: Do you see any improvement if you use a pipelined function, instead of building up the entire collection in memory and returning it all at once? Not sure why that would cause quite what you're seeing but might be worth comparing anyway as it would use less memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `bulk collect` instead of a plain loop (fetching records one by one) as there is no additional logic done in the loop. In general, always avoid switching a context (SQL to/from PL/SQL)

```
open curs_lvl_1;
fetch curs_lvl_1 bulk collect into res_type;
close curs_lvl_1;
```

Comment: Already tested, in fact that is my first code, but it generate the same problem.

Comment: Well, then take a closer look at `curs_lvl_1` and `curs_lvl_0` cursors. Make sure the table statistics are up-to-date.